# How do I make sure my text and textboxes are aligned horizontally?

Tags: html, forms

What is a quick and easy way to make sure that my text and textboxes are lined up correctly on all screen sizes?

[image]

Comment: Tables. (Or the related CSS `display` styles.)

Comment: No Tables for layout, please! :P

Comment: What HTML / CSS code are you using?

Comment: Actually, I suppose a grid system would work for this, but only if you can live with fixed-width columns.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
 form {display:table;}
 label {display:table-row}
 label span , input {display:table-cell;}
</style>

<form>
 <label>
  <span>Name:</span>
  <input type="text" name="Name"/>
 </label>
 <label>
  <span>Phone:</span>
  <input type="text" name="Phone"/>
 </label>
</form>
```

Works for IE8 and newer